# Getting error while resetting mysql root password

Tags: mysql, join, select

I am trying to reset password for `root` user and I have successfully executed below commands

```
service mysql stop
```

Created and saved a text file `/home/me/mysql-init` containing the following statement on a single line.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Started mysql server with the special --init-file option:

```
shell> mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

However, I am getting an error

```
    starting as process 51672 ...
51672 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
51672 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I am using Mysql Version `5.6` and following the given documentation 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Did you *read "Security" section of the manual?

Answer (score 3):

Change to this to use user as root:

> mysqld --user=root --init-file=/root/mysql-init &

Answer (score 1):

Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root! if you attempt to run mysqld as root. If you need to override this restriction for some reason, start mysqld with the user=root option.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while running mysql as Docker container, adding the following lines to mysql configuration file (my.cnf) helped:

```
[mysqld]
user=root
```